# Newtonsoft.Json Cannot create and populate list type

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, deserialization

I have a model:

```
[Serializable]
public class User
{
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set;}

    public bool isLoggedIn { get; set; }

    public CookieCollection Cookies { get; set; }

    [NonSerialized]
    public string Response = "";
}
```

Just trying to serialize and deserialize:

```
  string str = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(u, typeof(User), settings);
  User us = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(str);
```

I am getting an error:

```
     Cannot create and populate list type System.Net.CookieCollection. Path 'Cookies', line 1, position 92.
```

Json string:

```
    {"UserID":null,"UserName":"nazarkin659","Password":"Hakers659","isLoggedIn":true,"Cookies":[]}
```

I know that I am missing something, but I can' really understand what...

Comment: @AllanElder it is CookieCollection class and there is no private methods / fields / prop / contractors...

Comment: My bad; I read it as CookieContainer.

Comment: Try to use `List<Cookie>` instead of `CookieCollection`. You can convert it to list by `List<Cookie> cookieList = cookieCollection.OfType<Cookie>().ToList();`