# Deserialize a json serialized CookieCollection

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, json-deserialization, httpcookiecollection

In my code I have to Json serialize a CookieCollection object and pass it as string, to achieve this I do like this:

```
var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resp.Cookies);
```

resulting to the following json

```
[
 {
  "Comment": "",
  "CommentUri": null,
  "HttpOnly": false,
  "Discard": false,
  "Domain": "www.site.com",
  "Expired": true,
  "Expires": "1970-01-01T03:30:01+03:30",
  "Name": "version",
  "Path": "/",
  "Port": "",
  "Secure": false,
  "TimeStamp": "2015-06-01T12:19:46.3293119+04:30",
  "Value": "deleted",
  "Version": 0
 },
 {
  "Comment": "",
  "CommentUri": null,
  "HttpOnly": false,
  "Discard": false,
  "Domain": ".site.com",
  "Expired": false,
  "Expires": "2015-07-31T12:19:48+04:30",
  "Name": "ADS_7",
  "Path": "/",
  "Port": "",
  "Secure": false,
  "TimeStamp": "2015-06-01T12:19:46.3449217+04:30",
  "Value": "0",
  "Version": 0
 }
]
```

To deserialize this json I wanted to do something like this:

```
var cookies = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CookieCollection>(json);
```

But it fails and raise *JsonSerializationException* saying

> *Cannot create and populate list type System.Net.CookieCollection. Path '', line 1, position 1.*

So I changed my code to the following and its working now

```
var tmpcookies = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Cookie>>(json);
CookieCollection cookies = new CookieCollection();
tmpcookies.ForEach(cookies.Add);
```

I am just wondering why my first attempt fails? and if there is any nicer way of doing it.

Comment: As http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27449717/newtonsoft-json-cannot-create-and-populate-list-type says... Try to use List<Cookie> instead of CookieCollection. You can convert it to list by List<Cookie> cookieList = cookieCollection.OfType<Cookie>().ToList();

Comment: @PaulZahra I already have it as List<Cookie>! my question is why this `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CookieCollection>(json);` fails!

Comment: How is CookieCollection cookies = new CookieCollection();  the same as List<Cookie> ?

Comment: @har07 But List<T> implements both IEnumerable (as well as IEnumerable<T>) and ICollection which CoockieCollection implements too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSON.NET doesn't support deserializing non-generic `IEnumerable`s.

`CookieCollection` implements `IEnumerable` and `ICollection`, but not `IEnumerable<Cookie>`. When JSON.NET goes to deserialize the collection, it doesn't know what to deserialize the individual items in the `IEnumerable` into.

Contrast this with `IList<Cookie>` which has a generic type parameter. JSON.NET can determine what type each element in the resulting list should be.

You could fix this using the workaround discussed in the comments, or write a custom converter.